# How to prevent my makefile to relink due to static library

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have a Makefile which works well when there is not static library to compile:

```
CC              = g++ -std=c++11                                                                                                                                        

RM              = rm -f                                                                                                                                                 

NAME            = hello                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

SRCS            = Main.cpp \                                                                                                                                            
                  srcs/Controller.cpp \
                  ...                                                                                                         
                  srcs/Parser.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

OBJS            = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)                                                                                                                                       

CPPFLAGS        += -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror                                                                                                                             

all     : $(NAME)                                                                                                                                                       

$(NAME) : $(OBJS)                                                                                                                                                       
          $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS) -I./inc                                                                                                        

clean   :                                                                                                                                                               
          $(RM) $(OBJS)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

fclean  : clean                                                                                                                                                         
          $(RM) $(NAME)                                                                                                                                                 

re      : fclean all                                                                                                                                                    

.PHONY  : all clean fclean re
```

This makefile works and doesn't relink (when I type twice "make", it doesn't recompile and output "Nothing to be done for all")

But when I want to compile a static library, the "make" command recompile the library without outputing "Nothing to be done for all", here is the new Makefile containing the static lib:

```
CC              = g++ -std=c++11                                                                                                                                        

RM              = rm -f                                                                                                                                                 

NAME            = hello                                                                                                                                          

LIBNAME         = libhello.a                                                                                                                                     

SRCS            = srcs/Controller.cpp \
                  ...                                                                                                                                 
                  srcs/Parser.cpp                                                                                                                             

OBJS            = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)                                                                                                                                       

CPPFLAGS        += -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror                                                                                                                             

all     : $(NAME)                                                                                                                                                       

$(NAME) : $(OBJS)                                                                                                                                                       
          ar rc $(LIBNAME) $(OBJS)
          $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(LIBNAME) Main.cpp -I./inc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

clean   :                                                                                                                                                               
          $(RM) $(OBJS)                                                                                                                                                 
          $(RM) $(LIBNAME)                                                                                                                                              

fclean  : clean                                                                                                                                                         
          $(RM) $(NAME)                                                                                                                                                 

re      : fclean all                                                                                                                                                    

.PHONY  : all clean fclean re
```

How could I fix that problem to prevent the makefile to recompile when the static library has already been compiled and doesn't need to be recompiled ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding this recipe:

```
$(NAME) : $(OBJS)                                                                                                                                                       
      $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS) -I./inc
```

it is expecting that the default compile statement will be used to generate the object files and `make` will generate those object files before executing the rule.  and since it is not performing any compiles in this recipe, the parameter `-I./inc` is unneeded.

Without the header files being listed in the dependencies, changing a header file will fail to cause the associated source files to be recompiled.

Suggest:

```
HEADERS := ..

$(name): $(OBJS) 
<tab> $(CC)  -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS)

%.o:%.cpp $(HEADERS)
<tab> $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I./inc
```

Note in the line:

```
CPPFLAGS        += -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror
```

the `-W` turns off all the previously enabled warnings, probably not what you want, suggest removing that parameter.

Similar considerations need to be applied when creating the static library,  similar to:

this line:

```
$(NAME) : $(OBJS)                                                                                                                                                       
      ar rc $(LIBNAME) $(OBJS)
      $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(LIBNAME) Main.cpp -I./inc
```

becomes:

```
HEADER := ...

all: $(LIBNAME) $(NAME)

$(LIBNAME): $(OBJS)
<tab> ar rc -o $@ $^

%.o:%.cpp
<tab> $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I./inc 

$(NAME): main.o $(LIBNAME)
<tab> $(CC) $< -o $@ $(LFLAGS) -l$(LIBNAME)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot about your answer and your note about the -W flag!!

Comment: @user3629249 what you said about -W flags is totally wrong! as you can see in `man make`:
`-w  Inhibit all warning messages.`

and:
`-Wextra
           This enables some extra warning flags that are not enabled by -Wall. (This option used to be called -W.  The older name is still supported, but the newer name is more descriptive.)`

So `-W` flags is just the OLDER name of `-Wextra` (so put `-W` and `-Wextra` on the same line is useless, all Epitech' student do the same error because they are not abble to think by theirself and they just copied intranet's Makefile's example.

Comment: @Paul-Marie,   this option: -W  results in: Inhibit all warning messages. This is found on web page: [-W](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)

Comment: @user3629249 YES, but like I told to you, you are swapping `-w` and `-W`, the `-w` flags effictively result in "inhibit all warning", but `-W` (so in caps) is just the older name of `-Wextra`, still suported but no guarantee that it stays like this anymore in the future!

(See the first line of description at your web page).
Best Reguard.

Comment: Now I see, Capital 'W' .vs. lower case 'w'.  My error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `$NAME` is a phony target due to this rule:

```
all     : $(NAME)
```

I think the issue can be resolved by instead changing it to an actual target:

```
all     : $(LIBNAME)
```

Also, you have this rule:

```
$(NAME) : $(OBJS)
      ar rc $(LIBNAME) $(OBJS)
      $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(LIBNAME) Main.cpp -I./inc
```

It is a bit confusing:   The library is built as `$LIBNAME`, but then it goes on to link an executable named `$NAME`.   So everytime you make a change to `Main.cpp`, the library has to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule for `$(NAME)` doesn't actually make a file called `$(NAME)` (i.e. `hello`), so make will try and remake it every time. The recipe must match the rule (and this is why you should use automatic variables as in the last example below):

```
all: $(LIBNAME)
$(LIBNAME): $(OBJS)
  ar rc $(LIBNAME) $(OBJS)
```

GNU make also has built-in archive functionality, although it doesn't play well with parallel make:

```
ARFLAGS := rc
all: $(LIBNAME)($(OBJS))
```

A more idiomatic, parallel-safe way would be something like

```
ARFLAGS := rc
.PHONY: all
all: $(LIBNAME)
$(LIBNAME): $(OBJS)
  $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^
```